# How to add get request parameter in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to add get request parameter from url to controller in angularjs
e.g. my request is `http://localhost/abc-ang/#!/abc/8` and my controller code is

```
app.controller('AbcCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
   $http.get("src/public/add/:id").then(function(response) {
       $scope.abc = response.data;
   });
});
```

I want to replace `src/public/add/:id` to `src/public/add/8`
how can I do that dynamically?

My routing configuration is

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/abc', {
            templateUrl: "tpl/welcome.html"
        })
        .when('/abc/:wineId', {
            templateUrl: 'tpl/abc-details.html', 
            controller: 'AbcDetailCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/abc' });
}]);
```

Comment: app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/abc', {
                templateUrl: "tpl/welcome.html"
            })
            .when('/abc/:wineId', {
             templateUrl:'tpl/abc-details.html', 
             controller:'AbcDetailCtrl'
            })
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/abc' });
    }]);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access URL params in your code with [`$routeParams`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams):

From your comment your route is:

```
$routeProvider.when('/abc/:wineId', {
    templateUrl: 'tpl/abc-details.html',
    controller: 'AbcDetailCtrl'
});
```

So in your controller, you can get `wineId` value with:

```
app.controller('AbcCtrl', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
   $http.get("src/public/add/" + $routeParams.wineId).then(function (response) {
       $scope.abc = response.data;
   });
});
```